# How to specify procedures to be executed depending on data type of polymorphic variables

Tags: oop, polymorphism, fortran, fortran2003

Conside the following sample code:

```
module mod

implicit none

type :: typeBase1
    integer :: A1
end type

type :: typeBase2
    integer :: A3
end type

type :: typeBase3
    integer :: A3
end type

type, extends(typeBase1) :: typeDerived1
    ! Void
end type

type, extends(typeBase2) :: typeDerived2
    ! Void
end type

type, extends(typeBase3) :: typeDerived3
    ! Void
end type

type, extends(typeBase1) :: typeDerived11        
    ! Void
end type

type, extends(typeBase2) :: typeDerived21
    ! Void
end type

type, extends(typeBase3) :: typeDerived31
    ! Void
end type


type :: complexType
   class(typeBase1), pointer :: ptrBase1  ! typeBase1, 2 and 3 are extensible
   class(typeBase2), pointer :: ptrBase2
   class(typeBase3), pointer :: ptrBase3
end type

interface calcul
    subroutine calculA(obj1, obj2, obj3)
        import
        type(typeDerived1) :: obj1        ! typeDerived 1, 2 et 3 are derived type of typeBase1, 2 and 3 
        type(typeDerived2) :: obj2
        type(typeDerived3) :: obj3
    end subroutine
    subroutine calculB(obj1, obj2, obj3)
        import
        type(typeDerived11) :: obj1        ! typeDerived 11, 21 et 31 are derived type of typeBase1, 2 and 3 
        type(typeDerived21) :: obj2
        type(typeDerived31) :: obj3
    end subroutine
end interface calcul

contains

    subroutine calculComplexType(complex)
        type(ComplexType), intent(inout) :: complex

        call calcul(complex % ptrBase1, complex % ptrBase2, complex % ptrBase3)
    end subroutine

end module mod
```

What I am trying to do is that the subroutine calculComplexType calls a different version of the subroutine calcul, basing on the dynamic type of ptrBase1, ptrBase2 and ptrBase3.

The code does not work, because the compiler looks for a subroutine with the following interface:

```
subroutine calcul(obj1, obj2, obj3)
    class(typeBase1) :: obj1         
    class(typeBase1) :: obj2
    class(typeBase1) :: obj3
end subroutine
```

whatever the dynamic type of ptrBase1, ptrBase2 and ptrBase3 is.

My question is: is there a way in Fortran to write the interface calcul in order to automatically select a procedure basing on the dynamic type of the arguments?

I would like to avoid to use a long sequence of "select class".

Any suggestion to rewrite the code is welcome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify procedures to be executed depending on data type of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539050/how-to-specify-procedures-to-be-executed-depending-on-data-type-of-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible in Fortran; the best you can do with polymorphism is to use an overridden type-bound procedure, selecting a function based on the dynamic type of *one* particular entity.

However, depending on the nature of what `calcul` does, it may make more sense to define just one version of `calcul` that takes polymorphic arguments (i.e. `class(typeBase1)`, `class(typeBase2)`, `class(typeBase3)`), and deal with the dynamic type inside `calcul` itself. The benefits are twofold:

1. `calcul` may be able to test the type of each argument independently from the others. If that is the case, you will still have to write three `select type` constructs, but they won't be nested or duplicated.
2. It's likely that you can use single dispatch (with type-bound procedures) to remove the need for a `select type` construct completely.

It's difficult for me to think of a situation where the code in this question is really the best design you could use.

If `calcul` is really doing something completely "different" for each dynamic type, in a way that's relevant to the code that calls it, then the calling code should not be using polymorphic pointers (e.g. perhaps there should be a different `complexType` for each different `calcul`).

But if every version of `calcul` is doing essentially "the same" operation (as far as higher-level code knows/cares about), regardless of dynamic type, then there should only be one version and it should accept arguments that are of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

If you request dispatch based on all three arguments, it cannot be done. Some languages offer so called [multimethods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) for this.

In Fortran you can use normal single dispatch methods ([type-bound procedures](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-lin/GUID-9FE4A251-709A-4D23-8132-5C06F124CD0D.htm)), but in that case it can choose the subroutine only according to one argument.

Otherwise you have to use select the [select type](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-2B979B0C-8675-418B-BB8C-C6AA9548AFA4.htm) construct and make a `case` for every possible combination, be it inside one single procedure, or to select between more versions of it.

For two arguments, you can also consider the [double dispatch pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: A quibble with respect to type bound procedures - it can only choose the subroutine based on the object to the left of the binding name in the procedure designator in the call statement or function reference.  There's only one such object, hence you can't dispatch in a single step on three objects.  The object used for dispatch is often passed as the first argument, but it can be any other argument, or not even passed at all.  The OP could use this to implement a three step dispatch, but I think they are still up for a lot of typing.

Comment: It was a small simplification. You can of course have "class methods".